# motd message, when I log in using ssh, tells me I have a mail, how I can check it?

Tags: email, login

When I login into my vps,

```
ssh -D 127.0.0.1:1080 root@mydomain.com  

root@noxp.info's password:  
Linux born 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u1 i686  

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;  
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the  
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.  

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent  
permitted by applicable law.  
You have mail.  
Last login: Fri Feb 27 02:07:55 2015 from  my vps ip .
```

Where is the mail?

Comment: Type `mail`... and then `man mail`...

Comment: when i type mail ,there are two emails there ,but i have already read them,when i ssh -D 127.0.0.1:1080 root@mydomain.com next time, you have mail still there.

Comment: That's where the `man` page helps...

Comment: @WarrenYoung you may want `grep mail /etc/pam.d/login`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is given by your shell, according to the `MAIL` environment variable. If that variable contains the name of a file, and that file is non-empty, the shell will say "You have mail". The shell then remembers the timestamp of the file and won't mention mail again until that timestamp changes.

If the file is non-empty, *and* the modification time is later than the access time, then the shell will say "You have new mail", note the addition of the word "new" there.

You can read mail with the `mail` or `mailx` commands, but for a fullscreen experience try the `mutt` command. It's the only mail user agent I use, as I find it a lot quicker and handier to use than any GUI mail programs. It does get a bit of getting used to, though, but like `vim` you'll soon be glad you invested the time.

Comment: alpine is another alternative (and my personal favorite)